# Receive a PostAsync in FromBody as param

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to read a JSON string from Web API controller that is send through a `HttpClient.PostAsync()` method. But for some reason the `RequestBody` is always `null`.

My Request looks like this:

```
public string SendRequest(string requestUrl, StringContent content, HttpMethod httpMethod)
{
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ServerUrl) };
    var uri = new Uri(ServerUrl + requestUrl); // http://localhost/api/test

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

    HttpResponseMessage response;
    response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(response.ToString());
    }

    string stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return stringResult;
}
```

---

I call this method like this

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
string result = Request.SendRequest("/api/test", content, HttpMethod.Post);
```

---

Now currently my Web API controller method reads the send data like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostContract()
{
    string httpContent = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return httpContent;
}
```

This works fine. The `stringResult` property contains the string returned by the controller method. But I'd like to have my controller method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostContract([FromBody] string httpContent)
{
    return httpContent;
}
```

The request seems to be working, getting a `200 - OK`, but the `stringResult` from the `SendRequest` method is always `null`.

Why isn't the method where I'm using the `RequestBody` as parameter not working?

Comment: You forgot to show us what's the actual content. Give a sample content you want to get using `[FromBody]`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I added the code how I'm calling `SendRequest` method. I basically convert an object to a `JSON` string and send that as raw content.

Comment: wont this be looking for a form variable in the body called httpContent?

Comment: I think you could do it with a custom binder which essentially has the same code as your working example

Comment: @ToddMenier That was indeed the problem. I'm sending JSON to my controller, but the controller wants to convert it back to an object. It seems like you can't simply get the JSON string itself. Which is okay in my case. So changing the param to `PostContract([FromBody] Contract contract)` did the trick. Could you please post that as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're posting as `application/json`, the framework is attempting to deserialize it rather than providing the raw string. Whatever the type of `testObj` is in your sample, use that type for your controller action parameter and return type instead of `string`:

```
[HttpPost]
public MyTestType PostContract([FromBody] MyTestType testObj)
{
    return testObj;
}
```